# How do you sort a Standalone table that's already visible within ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm using ITableWindow2.FindViaStandaloneTable--that works.  I can get the ITableWindow for the stand alone table and the table from that.

Then I try to sort using an ITableSort.  No exceptions, but the table doesn't sort.  Is ITableSort the right approach or is there a different approach to sorting within a Table Window?

```
ITableSort sort= new TableSortClass();
sort.Fields = "MDATE";
sort.Ascending["MDATE"] = true;
sort.Table = standAloneTable.Table;
sort.Sort(null);
```

The goal is to programmatically sort a field. The way an end-user would manually right click a column on an attribute table and sort ascending or descending.

Answer (score 4):

No, ITableSort will not help you in this case. It returns a cursor which you can use to iterate through records sorted in the desired order.

To answer your question, I am sorry to say that sorting records in a table window does not seem to be exposed anywhere in the ArcObjects API.

Comment: +1 I wonder if this could be hacked by using spy++ to see what winapi messages are sent when interactively sorting a table, then writing a command to send those same messages.